# C++ assign variable value from SQL Server SELECT

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server

I've got a script that does a bunch of SQL inserts but I've been trying to add a section that assigns the returned value of a select query into a variable.

The code I've been using to do the inserts is:

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLCHAR*)"BULK INSERT mytable FROM 'C:/dir/myfile.csv' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');", SQL_NTS)) {
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
```

That all works fine, but I can't figure out how to use the output of a query. The output will be a single int value, which I'd like to assign to an int variable.

Apologies if this is something that's blindingly obvious.

**EDIT**

Based on the answer below, the following has now worked for me. Thanks!

```
SQLRETURN    retcode;
SQLHSTMT     hstmt; // I use my own stmnthndl(sqlstatementhandle) below, this line left in for demonstration

retcode = SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT count(*) FROM mytable;",SQL_NTS);
SQLINTEGER   sCustID;
SQLLEN cbCustID;

if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS) {
    while (TRUE) {
        retcode = SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle);
        if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {

            // get the first column
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &sCustID, 0, &cbCustID);

            //You can now print it
            cout << "CustID:" << sCustID;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SQLGetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715441(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the data for a single column in the resultset. Taken from [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715441(v=vs.85).aspx#Anchor_10), first you execute the SQL query with [`SQLExecDirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713611(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
SQLRETURN    retcode;
SQLHSTMT     hstmt;

retcode = SQLExecDirect(hstmt,
   (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT CUSTID, NAME, PHONE FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY 2, 1, 3",
   SQL_NTS);
```

Then you can get the data, I show a reduced version of the same [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715441(v=vs.85).aspx#Anchor_10):

```
SQLINTEGER   sCustID, cbCustID;

if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS) {
   while (TRUE) {
      retcode = SQLFetch(hstmt);
      if (retcode == SQL_ERROR || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
         show_error();
      }
      if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO){

         // get the first column
         SQLGetData(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &sCustID, 0, &cbCustID);

         //You can now print it
         fprintf(out, "CustID: %-5d", sCustID);
      } else {
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

The syntax of [`SQLGetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715441(v=vs.85).aspx) is:

> ```
> SQLRETURN SQLGetData(
>       SQLHSTMT       StatementHandle,
>       SQLUSMALLINT   Col_or_Param_Num,
>       SQLSMALLINT    TargetType,
>       SQLPOINTER     TargetValuePtr,
>       SQLLEN         BufferLength,
>       SQLLEN *       StrLen_or_IndPtr);
> ```

With:

- `StatementHandle`: the handle to the executed SQL query.
- `Col_or_Param_Num`: the column number, which starts at 1.
- `TargetType`: the data type, you can probably use `SQL_INTEGER`, see [SQL data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710150(v=vs.85).aspx) and [C data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714556(v=vs.85).aspx).
- `TargetValuePtr`: the pointer to the output data.
- `BufferLength`: the length, but is not used for fixed length data such as integers.
- `StrLen_or_IndPtr`: an optional output that can return the length of the data or an error code.

**Note**: like you commented you might need to cast the SQL query to `SQLCHAR *` since `SQLCHAR` is an `unsigned char`, see [the data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714556(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks so much for this, had to make one change - I don't know if it's to do with how the rest of my code is laid out? I had to add (SQLCHAR*) in front of the query